# why my jquery script doesn't work in my include php file?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I try to understand why my jquery script doesn't work at all in my php included files.
index.php:

```
<?PHP  
session_start();
include_once("./tools/globalFunction.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Jojo Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?PHP 
        include_once("application.php");
        include_once("layout/menu.php");
        include_once("layout/loginModal.php");
        include_once("layout/container.php");
        include_once("layout/footer.php");  
        ?>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./editor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/javaScriptGlobalFunction.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

menu.php:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavConnexion">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">    
            <li id="adminButton" class="nav-item">
                <?php
                if (!$_SESSION['admin']){?>
                <button id="connexion" class="btn btn-dark" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Connexion</button> <?php ;}
                else {?>
                <button id="deconnexion" class="btn btn-dark" href="#" >Déconnexion</button> <?php ;}    
                ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

javaScriptGlobalFunction.php:

```
$("#Connexion").click(function(){
    alert('connexion')
});
$("#Deconnexion").click( function() {
    alert('déconnexion')
});
```

With those code lines it doesn't work whereas if i put the jquery script include and my script at the end of the menu file like :

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavConnexion">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">    
            <li id="adminButton" class="nav-item">
                <?php
                if (!$_SESSION['admin']){?>
                <button id="connexion" class="btn btn-dark" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Connexion</button> <?php ;}
                else {?>
                <button class="btn btn-dark" href="#" id="deconnexion">Déconnexion</button> <?php ;}    
                ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#deconnexion").click(function(){alert('deconnexion')});
</script>
```

It's run... Is there something i didn't seen well or i have to place jquery and script directly in each file?

Comment: Because the javascript in your include runs *before* you have included jquery (`<script src=..jquery`).  You need to review the browser console for errors (unknown function / `$` not defined) and check the *rendered* html.

Comment: Addition, Looks like you are trying to include `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js`, but judging by your post your file is named `javaScriptGlobalFunction.php`, when in really should be named `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js`  A typo in the question? Or do they really have different extentions?

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin if it's a php "include" (via `include_once`) then it should end in `.php` - it's a php-parsed text file (in this case just containing javascript).  If it ended in `.js` then it probably would be included with a `<script src=` tag.  However, you are correct in that *both* `javaScriptGlobalFunction.php` (via `include_once`) **and** `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js` (via `script src`) are included - so it's not clear which it should be, but ultimately shouldn't matter (except that the .js script is after the jquery one, so would work...)

Comment: @freedomn-m, I am referring to this - `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/javaScriptGlobalFunction.js"></script>`. And i see no `include` or `include_once` with `javaScriptGlobalFunction.php` in OP's code. Might have missed it

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin yes, spotted that after I started the comment - I updated my comment.  Look at the first 3 lines of the first code block for the php include.  Edit: a second look shows this is a different filename... the plot thickens :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not working because in `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js` you're trying to find elements by id with first letter in uppercase, while in html id is all lowercase.
In `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js` change

```
$("#Connexion").click(function(){
    alert('connexion')
});
$("#Deconnexion").click( function() {
    alert('déconnexion')
});
```

to

```
$("#connexion").click(function(){
    alert('connexion');
});
$("#deconnexion").click(function() {
    alert('déconnexion');
});
```

Comment: If this was the case, it wouldn't work when the file is included at the bottom (after the script include)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you mean. Could you explain?

Comment: OP stated when he/she defines the scripts at the bottom of his/her page, everything works as is

Comment: @DarkBee In OP's last code example, when it's defined at the bottom of page, id is correctly lowercased

Comment: Valid point - But i was only making clear what @freedomn-m meant with the comment

Comment: As i pointed out above, You seem to be missing the fact that the content of `javaScriptGlobalFunction.js` is not present in OP's post. Look carefully. It is not there. My guess that file naming went wrong at some point and JS right now is not included at all.

Comment: I'll retract my comment, I suspect I misinterpreted "if I put my script at the end" as putting the *same* script at the end, but looks like it is indeed a different script.  I can confirm that IDs are case sensitive, so this is a potentially valid solution (though I still believe the *initial* issue is that `$(function..` code appears before `<script src=jquery`) - so hard to tell with the question as it stands.

Comment: i have tried to solve this problem for the last two days... the simpliest things are the hardest to correct. thanks a lot!

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Initially I thought that as well. But since there is a script tag with src `./js/javaScriptGlobalFunction.js` and no other mentions of `javaScriptGlobalFunction.php` I assumed that was simply a typo

Answer (score 0):

At first korrekt lower/higher key:
$("#Deconnexion") != id="connexion"

Also your script will run befor your html is rendered by browser.
Put it into

```
$(function () {
  $("#connexion").click(function(){
    alert('connexion');
  });
  $("#deconnexion").click(function() {
    alert('déconnexion');
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's in doc.ready, `$` still not defined if it's before `<script src=..jquery`